# Incorrect result from MYSQL search script php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to make this script to work. It's search engine for my site but return strange(for me) result. It's include also pagination.

```
$searchTerm = trim($_POST['term']);
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM images WHERE caption LIKE '%$searchTerm%'");

$nr = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
    $term = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['term']);
} else {
  $term = 1;
}
$itemsPerPage = 12;
$lastPage = ceil($nr / $itemsPerPage);
if ($term < 1) {
$term = 1;
} else if ($term > $lastPage) {
$term = $lastPage;
}
$centerPages = "";
$sub1 = $term - 1;
$sub2 = $term - 2;
$add1 = $term + 1;
$add2 = $term + 2;
if ($term == 1) {
  $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $term . '</span> &nbsp;';
  $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?term=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($term == $lastPage) {
  $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?term=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
  $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $term . '</span> &nbsp;';
} else if ($term > 2 && $term < ($lastPage - 1)) {
  $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?term=' . $sub2 . '">' . $sub2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
  $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?term=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
  $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $term . '</span> &nbsp;';
  $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?term=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
  $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?term=' . $add2 . '">' . $add2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($term > 1 && $term < $lastPage) {
  $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?term=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
  $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $term . '</span> &nbsp;';
  $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?term=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
}
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($term - 1) * $itemsPerPage .',' .$itemsPerPage;
$sql2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id desc $limit");
$paginationDisplay = "";

if ($lastPage != "1"){
    $paginationDisplay .= 'Page <strong>' . $term . '</strong> from ' . $lastPage. '&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; ';

if ($term != 1) {
    $previous = $term - 1;
    $paginationDisplay .=  "&nbsp;  <a href='result-$previous.html' id=\"prev\"> Prev</a> ";
}
$paginationDisplay .= '<span class="paginationNumbers">' . $centerPages . '</span>';
if ($term != $lastPage) {
    $nextPage = $term + 1;
    $paginationDisplay .=  "&nbsp;  <a href='result-$nextPage.html' id=\"next\"> Next</a> ";
}
}
 $output = '';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)){

$caption = $row['caption'];
$name = $row['name'];
$id = $row['id'];

$output .= "<div class=\"container_image\">";
$output .= "<a href=\"/pic-".$row['id'].".html\"><img src=\"/upload/".$row['name']."\" width=\"210\" height=\"150\"/></a>";
$output .= "</div>";
}
```

This is the form

```
<form action="../search.php" class="search-wrapper cf" method="post">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Searching..." required="" name="term">
   <button type="submit">Търсене</button>
</form>
```

Whenever I search some word it gave me whole data from database table.

What I think that the problem is in SQL query but I'm not sure what exactly and how to fix it.

p.s. I also know that is not secure. I just want to make it work..

Comment: I'm not sure what you got or were expecting to get from this.  What does "strange result" mean exactly?

Comment: Have you tried executing the SQL query on its own?

Comment: Lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: It doesn't matter what I write in search form the result is always the same - last 24 items in db table. @MarcB, as I wrote in the end I know about this, thank's anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a form with method POST and try to receive a value from $_GET['term']. So change it to $_POST['term'].

You are using $sql just for mysqli_num_rows. There is no WHERE clause in the sql2 statement from which you feed your output.

Try to begin simple and improve it step by step, start with:

```
$searchTerm = trim($_POST['term']);
$itemsPerPage = 12;
$page = 1;

$sql = "SELECT id, name, caption FROM images";
$sql.= " WHERE caption LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%'";
$sql.= " ORDER BY id DESC";
$sql.= " LIMIT ".(($page - 1) * $itemsPerPage).",".$itemsPerPage;

$mid = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$output = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mid)) {
    $output.= "<div class=\"container_image\">";
    $output.= "<a href=\"/pic-".$row['id'].".html\"><img src=\"/upload/".$row['name']."\" width=\"210\" height=\"150\"/></a>";
    $output.= "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Thank's. I didn't saw this. This fixed the pagination but now doesn't matter what word I search always return whole data from table ~3000 images.

Comment: If I put `WHERE` in `$sql2` and remove it from `$sql` .. is the same again.

Comment: I'm a little confuse. I've already tried to put `WHERE` clause in `sql2` instead of `sql` and the result is same.

Comment: @Goro: What do you mean? Have you tried the provided code and does it work?

Comment: Can you help me a little with pagination also?

Comment: Only a little: don't use "term" for search word and page. If you mix a POST form and GET href links for pagination, then use $_REQUEST for incoming values and don't forget to include the search word in your href links. Or use instead javascript to send your POST form with the page you want.

Answer (score 2):

You're running two queries. One that searches for your keywords (`$sql`) and one that just fetches some `limit`ed rows WITHOUT using your keywords (`$sql2`).

You never actually use any of the data from your first `$sql` query, so the filtered results are simply thrown out. So, yeah, you'll never get "search" results, since the query that actually gets used/displayed has absolutely NO relationship whatsoever to the search terms you entered.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I use the query from `$sql2` in my `while loop`.

Comment: Yes, but you don't use the query from `$sql` anywhere.

Comment: Exactly. `$sql2` doesn't have a `WHERE` clause, so your search terms are never applied to it. That means you're fetching ALL of the records (subject to the `LIMIT` clause quantities).

Comment: So what I must put this `WHERE` clause in `$sql2` not in `$sql`? I've tried this before but is same .. just return whole data from db.

Comment: Sorry but if I really know it I will not ask here.